# find_by_sql which model should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

There are three tables:

1. users
2. schedules
3. schedules_users

The user-model and the schedules-model each have the `has_and_belongs_to_many`-relationship.

Now I simply want to do this:

```
user_id_binded = Schedule/User/Object/#I dont know!#.find_by_sql ["SELECT schedules_users.user_id FROM schedules_users WHERE schedules_users.schedule_id = ?", schedule.id]
@user_schedules_binded = User.find(user_id_binded)
```

**BUT** the return-value of the first `find_by_sql` must be a model, as I understood the Rails.Api correctly.
It's neither a user-model-return-value or a schedule-model-return-value.

In the schedules_users-table are all relationships between users and schedules.
So I want to get all users which are binded to a specific schedule.

First I thought this should be the right way to solve it, but at that moment I didn't know that the return-value must be a model.
**How could I solve this problem?**

Comment: Why don't you create `ScheduleUser` model and specify `has_many through` relation instead?

Comment: That's why :P http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: `has_many through` relation doesn't brake this principle.

Comment: I agree, has_many :through is the way to go here, and i don't understand why you think it's not DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a schedule ID and want the users in the end - that can be done easier by join statement like `@user_schedules_binded = User.joins(:schedules).where(schedules: { id: schedule_id })`

Or, if you have the schedule object, `schedule.users` will do the same, both going through schedules_users table.

Comment: THIS is pretty awesome! Thank you very much. One more question: The current output is ` #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x4465890>`. How can I get the users' names? `@user_schedule_binded.first.name` returns only the first entry, but I want all names of the users.

Comment: `schedule.users.each do |user|
       user.name
   end` my solution. Thanks for help.